# how can I calculate impedance matching for STM32WLE5 RF network?

Tags: stm32, impedance-matching

I am attempting to compute an impedance matching network by following the guidelines outlined in the ST Application Note - [AN5457](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5457-rf-matching-network-design-guide-for-stm32wl-series-stmicroelectronics.pdf). However, on page 24, the formula and calculations appear perplexing to me due to the presence of a negative value under the square root.

[image]

Even though the provided example calculation values for L1 (4.45 nH) and C1 (5.53 pF) are intended for a 14 dB power setup at 868 MHz, they don't correspond with the component values found in the reference design, such as the [MB1720](https://file.io/MO1x2FtYmQc6). For instance, besides L1, the reference design includes a 0 Ohm resistor, and for C1, it features 0.7 pF.
[image]

What further confuses me is that these values are allocated to a high-power reference design - 22 dB components too.
Kindly advise how a matching network is calculated? Does the reference design show wrong component values or are the Application Note calculations misleading?

Comment: You have little red markers on the schematic implying that every node is 50 ohm and, that definitely will not be the case so, please explain what that is all about. To explain each component in detail proper figures are needed for the IC output impedance and antenna impedance.

Comment: I have revised the post and included a link to the Schematics along with the more detailed screenshot.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the 50 ohm red markers are all about. These cannot be correct at all and, although you are distracted by the process, I am distracted by those markers. This doesn't help me explain to you what might be going on here. I mean, if you just wanted the theory on how a pi-filter can match different impedance that's easy but, it's all the unknowns such as antenna impedance and source impedance that makes this a mammoth process to explain. Start with humbler beginnings is my advice then learn from that level.

Comment: And please provide a direct link to the source document. I won't download anything from unknown sources for my own protection.

Comment: those 50 ohms are impedance of PCB traces, from MCU RF pins to RF switch and to antenna

Comment: Direct link" https://www.st.com/resource/en/schematic_pack/mb1720_schematics.zip

Comment: If that's what they indicate then it's a mess because using a 50 ohm trace of any significant length with an impedance source or load that isn't 50 ohm is going to produce problems. If on the other hand those traces are short, then there's no need to state that they are 50 ohm. That's my confusion here.